# Uploading different file per thread in Jmeter

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, bad-request

I want to test out the file upload time in our system. I created 100 files and put it in the folder.

Files have same data instead invoice no. which I parameterized. But when i run the script I am getting the Bad request error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ek50.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxQmN.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going for [Directory Listing Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter)

1. Install Directory Listing Config plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
2. Add `jp@gc - Directory Listing Data Source` element to your Test Plan
3. Specify the following parameters:

   - Source Directory -> `Test Invoices`
   - Destination Variable Name: `invoice`

     [image: JMeter Directory Listing Config]
4. That's it, you will now be able to upload a new file with each thread/iteration with the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler